# Is there a good practice to remember Regex rules?

Tags: c#, .net

I once a while use Regex, but every time I have to reread the matching rules, it is so hard to remember.

Is there a good source helping people remember and understand those matching rules?

Comment: Continually using the syntax is the best way. Unfortunately repetition is often the truest form of teaching.

Comment: @Giswin Try Replacing., where ever you want in a more generic way. For example,
if you want to delete all the (say only) 5 "strings" in your code or file, don't just delete those 5 strings manually  . Just try., `"[^"]*\"` . Doing this way will be funny and simultaneously will improve you skill. I am doing this way and continuously learning Regex too.

Comment: Do you know about DFA's/NFA's? If not check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton for me at least, it was essential in really understand the concept. Before that I was just hacking shit together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a site that offers a "cheat sheet" for the .NET flavor of regex:

- http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

Though it's really a matter of just knowing it or not (like knowing C#, JavaScript, or any of the other languages). Repetition and practice will persevere.

Comment: This is very useful link. I will come to here every time when I use it.

Answer (score 1):

in visual studio i do find/replacing with regex, helps me practice.  Especially in the entity framework